# How can i save check boxes value to database in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am new to ruby on rails and active admin, I need to create check boxes for registration fees. while I checked, the value from checkbox is not saved to the database. can anyone help me ??

```
  form do |f|
       f.inputs do
       f.input :name, label: "Student Name"
       f.input :dob,:label => "Date of Birth"
       f.input :age,:label => "Age"
       f.input :gender, as: :radio, :label => "Gender", :collection => [ "Male", "Female"] 
       f.input :reg_fee, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => RegChargeSetup.all.map{|v| ["#{v.reg_fee}"]}
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are taking `array of arrays`, instead you should take `array of strings`,

So, change

```
f.input :reg_fee, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => RegChargeSetup.all.map{|v| ["#{v.reg_fee}"]}
```

to,

```
f.input :reg_fee, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => RegChargeSetup.all.map{|v| "#{v.reg_fee}"}



form do |f|
       f.inputs do
       f.input :name, label: "Student Name"
       f.input :dob,:label => "Date of Birth"
       f.input :age,:label => "Age"
       f.input :gender, as: :radio, :label => "Gender", :collection => [ "Male", "Female"] 
       f.input :reg_fee, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => RegChargeSetup.all.map{|v| "#{v.reg_fee}"}
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Comment: I changed form input as shown above, but it doesn't work for me. What do I have to do? value for this registration fees are not saved to the database..still

Comment: what is the datatype of your field?

Comment: datatype as string  **t.string :reg_fee**